# If $\cos A = \sin B$ , does $A+B = 90$ degrees?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\cos A = \sin B$ , does $A+B = 90$ degrees?

My school teacher says that this works but I was unable to understand how. I have been unable to find a proof for this. How does this work?

*Edit* I should add that this is for an acute case

Comment: Only if A and B are acute.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a picture says more than 1000 words:

[image: image of circle with angles A and B and the corresponding sines and cosines]

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

$$\cos A=\sin B=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-B\right)$$ so that

$$A=\pm\left(\frac\pi2-B\right)+2k\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$\cos(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Comment: The question has been edited since you posted your answer.  The OP is asking specifically about the acute case.

Answer (score 0):

When $\sin(a) = \cos(b)$ then $\cos(b) = \cos(\pi/2 - a)$ so:
$b = 2k\pi \pm (\pi/2-a)$

So there are two possibilites for a + b.
$a + b = 2k\pi + \pi/2$ or $2k\pi+2a-\pi/2$

I used the fact that if $\cos(x) = \cos(a) => x = 2k\pi\pm a $.

Because both of the angles are acute, then we can say that: $0\leq a+b\leq \pi$

So $0\leq 2k\pi+\pi/2\leq \pi$. This inequality only correct if $k=0$. So one possibility is that:

$a + b = \pi/2$

So what if $0\leq 2k\pi - \pi/2 +  2a \leq \pi$? Then this means that(the only way that $a$ becomes acute, is if $k = 0$)

$\pi/4 \leq a \leq 3\pi/4$

if this happens, then $a$ and $b$ are only acute(or right angle) when $a = \pi/2$

Then $b$ becomes zero, then we can say that even now $a + b = \pi/2$.

Comment: The question has been edited since you posted your answer.  The OP is asking specifically about the acute case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you already solved goniometric equations, but I solved this one for you:

$$\cos(A) = \sin(B) \iff cos(A) = cos(90°-B)$$

$$ \iff A = 90° - B + 360°*K \quad \text{or} \quad A = -(90° - B) + 360°*K$$

where $K \in \mathbb{Z}$

When $A,B$ are angles between $0°$ and $90°$, we see (from the first equation) that $A + B = 90°$ is the only option (take $K = 0$).

So in particular, the answer to your question follows because if $A,B$ are accute, then:

$$cos(A) = sin(B) \iff cos(A) = cos(90°-B) \iff A = 90° - B  \iff A + B = 90°$$

Comment: The question was edited while you were writing your answer.  The OP is asking specifically about the acute case.

Comment: I'll edit, thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true.

**Proof 1 using the unit circle:**

The equation $\cos A = \sin B$ together with the fact that both are acute implies that the points on the circle $(\cos A, \sin A)$ and $(\sin B, \cos B)$ are the same. $(\cos A, \sin A)$ is at angle $A$ counter-clockwise from the horizontal, and $(\sin B, \cos B)$ is at angle $B$ clockwise from verticle. Since $A$ and $B$ are acute, the point is somewhere between $0$ and $90$ degrees counterclokwise from horizontal, and if you draw a diagram you will see that $A + B = 90^\circ$.

**Proof 2 using algebra:**

Write $B = 90 - B'$ for an acute angle $B'$. Then $\sin B = \sin (90 - B') = \cos B'$. Since $A$ and $B'$ are acute and $\cos A = \cos B'$, $A = B'$.

Answer (score 0):

Given: $A,\,B$ are acute angles and

$$\cos A=\sin B\tag{1}$$
Prove: $A+B=90^\circ$

1. Square both sides to get:

$$ \cos^2 A=\sin^2B $$

Thus

$$\cos^2A-\sin^2B=0\tag{2}$$

But since $\cos^2A-\sin^2B=\cos(A+B)$ this gives

$$\cos(A+B)=0\tag{3}$$

In order that acute angles $A$ and $B$ satisfy equation $(3)$ it must be the case that

$$  A+B=90^\circ$$

Answer (score -1):

If you assume $A+B=90^{\circ}$, then $A=90^{\circ}-B$, so $\sin A = \sin(90-B)$. $\sin(90-B)=\cos B$ so $\sin A = \cos B$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  To obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$,  and $\cot x$, type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode.  Please see this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Also use ^{\circ} for $^{\circ}$ (degrees) in math mode.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

But this isn't the only solution.
$$\cos A=\sin(A+pi/2)=\sin B \implies B=A+\pi/2 +2k\pi$$
for $k=0$, $B=A+\pi/2  \iff B-A= \pi/2$.